# Сreate a manage-zone using the google cloud console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

Problem: I can't create managed-zones using the google cloud console.
What did I do?

1. Created a service account
2. Add role **DNS Administrator**
3. Created a json key
4. Executed the command

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account test235643@developer-dns-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/home/d.reznikov/Downloads/developer-dns-test-5a2088479459.json --project=developer-dns-testing
```

4. Executed the command

```
gcloud dns managed-zones create my_zone --dns-name my.zone.com. --description "My zone!"
```

I get error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zones.create) User [test235643@developer-dns-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access project [developer-dns-test] (or it may not exist): Forbidden
```

Please help, maybe something else needs to be installed in the google cloud settings?

Comment: The error message says you do not have permission in the project **developer-dns-test**. Go back to the IAM console, select the project, and double-check which roles you assigned to the service account.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, I really did not set the correct role

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project name is slightly different between the command used to activate the service account and the error message.

Command:
gcloud auth activate-service-account test235643@developer-dns-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/home/d.reznikov/Downloads/developer-dns-test-5a2088479459.json **--project=developer-dns-testing**

Error msg:
ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zones.create) User [test235643@developer-dns-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access project **[developer-dns-test]** (or it may not exist): Forbidden

I would double check the project name and re authorize the service account using the correct one. Then retry to create the zone.